# Python For Loop Range(Len()) Redundancy

Tags: loops, for-loop

Wheever I see a loop that looks like this:

```
for i in range(len(string_1)):
```

isn't that the same as

```
for i in string_1:
```

They each cycle through the entire string, isn't the first way just the long way of doing so?

Comment: they are equivalent, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not exactly same.

```
array = [2,4,6,8,10]

for i in array:
    print i
```

would print "2 4 6 8 10" (in separate lines)

```
for i in range(len(array)):
    print i
```

would print "0 1 2 3 4" (in separte lines)

They cycle through different arrays, first one cycles through your given array. But second one cycles through a different array which is produced by "range" method.

Read more about python's range method here - http://pythoncentral.io/pythons-range-function-explained/

Comment: Isnt even having range redundant, because just len will get you the same as range(len))?  Isnt it just a list of numbers in the end?

Comment: range is redundant is this use case where you want to traverse an array. However, there are many use cases where you need range arrays.